# Does the ReSharper unit test runner run tests sequentially or in parallel with MbUnit?

Tags: .net, resharper, mbunit, sequential

Does the ReSharper unit test runner run tests sequentially or in parallel (and then, is each test in a separate thread)? I am using MBUnit test framework.

Answer (score 4):

VS2008 + R# 4.5 runs tests in parallel provided that you mark them as such with MbUnit's Parallelizable attribute. If you don't, they will be run sequentially. Either way, it won't run **all** your tests at once in different threads since that would kill test performance, but rather uses a limited thread pool.

Comment: Correct.  You can configure the number of threads in play using [DegreeOfParallelism(n)]

Answer (score 0):

It does so sequentailly. (using R# 4.0 with VS 2008)